# Algorithm problem Queues implemented in linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Queues implemented in linked list, when performing insertion operations ( ).
A. only modify the head pointer.
B. the head and tail pointers may need to be modified.
C. modify only the tail pointer
D. both the head and tail pointers must be modified.

I asked the GPT but it give me two answers B and C, what is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, in queues implemented using linked-lists, **both** the head and tail pointers may need to be modified when performing insertion operations.

When a new item is inserted into a queue, it becomes the **new tail** of the queue. So the tail pointer needs to be updated to point to the newly inserted item. Also if the queue was empty before the insertion, the head pointer also needs to be updated to point to the newly inserted item.

So the correct answer is **B**. Both the head and tail pointers **must** be modified when performing insertion operations in queues implemented using linked-lists.

*Maybe that's why ChatGPT confused and selected two answers.*

Comment: So B will be the correct answer,because D use "must". If you only insert the tail pointer, you don't need to modified the head pointer .

Comment: @nullskymc yea I meant `B`, the one with `must`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific implementation.

The "tail" pointer needs to be modified either way, so A is wrong.

D is wrong because as you've already figured out, if the head pointer is already set, you need not modify the tail pointer. So "must" doesn't hold here.

Whether you may need to modify the head pointer now depends on the specific implementation. An implementation that represents an "empty queue" as `head = tail = null` has to update the head pointer when inserting into an empty queue, as Yousha already pointed out. In this case, B would be the correct answer.

However, there's also the implementation variant of using *dummy nodes*. When doing it this way, the empty queue will have `head = dummy node`, so an insertion will not have to update the head pointer; it only needs to update the tail pointer. C would be correct in this case.